# Java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format for custom web server

Tags: java, ssl

I am trying to renew a SSL certificate for Java based custom web server. I created csr and ordered the SSL certificate. I received SSL certificate in X.509 and PKCS#7 format. I imported the certificate in my keystore and when I am starting the webserver, I am getting an exception

> "Java.io.IOException: Invalid Keystore Format"

I used below command to import the certificate in my keystore

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file mycertificate.p7s -keystore mykeystore.jks -alias "alias"
```

Is this happening because my keystore type is "jks" and my certificate is in PKCS#7 format?

Comment: What web-server are we talking about. How do you specify the keystore. Are you sure it is an JKS store? (should start with hex "FE ED FE ED").

Comment: @Robert - The web server is custom and written in Java.Yes, I am sure about the keystore being JKS.

Comment: How did you import and/or convert your original files into JKS?

Comment: @Bruno I have edited the question with command I used to import the certificate.

Comment: Did the import complete without errors? Does keytool -list -v work? Does the web server expect a JKS keystore?

Comment: @EJP - Yes to all your questions.

Comment: Please post the full exception and stack trace, edited into your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. The issue has been resolved by using keystore file in code instead of certificate file.